# Tomcat 7 and Virtual hosts

Tags: tomcat, virtualhost

I am trying ti set up two separate sites on one Tomcat server using virtual hosting.
I have the following in my server.xml file

```
    <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
  </Host>
<Host name="domain1.com"  appBase="/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/domain1"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
<Alias>www.domain1.com</Alias>
</Host>
```

I can browse easily to IP_Address/domain1, but when I try to go directly to domain1.com I get a page not found. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Can not comment therefore using answer section.

Please verify if you have added "domain1.com" to your host file. Also port should be specified while opening link from browser.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. The issue was pretty stupid. I didn't realize that Tomcat reauires a ROOT folder inside the application folder. After placing the site in /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/domain1/ROOT everything works fine. Thank you.